# Excel:Too Many Arguments For OR, and AND

Tags: windows-10, microsoft-excel

```
=IF(AND(OR(K5=4,K5=4.25),OR(J5=16,J5=17)),O5:Q5="X","X"," ")
```

Here is the formula in question.

What I'm trying to do is if `K5` is either equal to 4 or 4.25, and if `J5` is equal to either 16 or 17 and cells `O5` to `Q5` have no "X" in them, it should print "X". If not, " ".

What do I do, what is my mistake?

Comment: Your `IF` has too many arguments. You probably need to delete the `,"X",` part and replace it with a simple `,`. The structure of an `IF` is condition,true,false.

Answer (score 1):

You need to use the below written Formula, remember it's an Array Formula so finish it with **Ctrl+Shift+Enter**.

```
 {=IF(AND(OR(K5=4,K5=4.25),OR(J5=16,J5=17),O5:Q5<>"X"),"X","")}
```

**NB:** *The reason behind the Error you are getting is that, your Formula has wrong Syntax. You have used **=** sign where **<>** was needed also, you have used extra **)**, which was not at all required !!*

*Hope this help you.*